# Eigenfunctions of the Dirac Hamiltonian with time-dependent electromagnetic potential

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, mathematical-physics, hamiltonian, dirac-equation

I am not looking for explicit solutions to the eigenvalue equations, but rather for general function spaces.

For free Dirac equation without potentials, the solutions of the Dirac equation, or equivalently the eigenfunctions of Dirac Hamiltonian, are elements of Sobolov space of order 2 on $L^2$, with tensor product of $\mathbb{C}^4$.

How does this solution space change with respect to external time-dependent electromagnetic 4-potentials $A^\mu$? Or in other words, which wavefunctions $\psi$ are suitable solutions (and correspondingly their time-evolutions) when $A^\mu$ is continuous/differentiable/non-continuous/etc?